# Vue - Disable button when item is added to cart. Enable when it's removed

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to add functionality to my addToCart button located in ProductCard. I need it to be disabled once the cupcake has been added to my cart array. When removed via the removeItem/ clearCart in MiniCart I need the button to be enabled again. I've tried if else statements and tried adding all kinds of functionality that I've Google's but have yet to succeed. I'd really appreciate some help ^^

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        cart: [],
        cupcake: [{
            title: 'Cream',
            price: 12.99,
            image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/1055270/pexels-photo-1055270.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260',
            id: 1,
            quantity: 1
        },
        {
            title: 'Choc',
            price: 10.99,
            image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/1055272/pexels-photo-1055272.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260',
            id: 2,
            quantity: 1
        },
        {
            title: 'Frosting',
            price: 14.99,
            image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/1055271/pexels-photo-1055271.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260',
            id: 3,
            quantity: 1
        },
        {
            title: 'Berry',
            price: 9.99,
            image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/3081657/pexels-photo-3081657.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260',
            id: 4,
            quantity: 1
        },
        {
            title: 'Deluxe',
            price: 19.99,
            image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/1998634/pexels-photo-1998634.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260',
            id: 5,
            quantity: 1
        },
        {
            title: 'Oreo',
            price: 19.99,
            image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/783274/pexels-photo-783274.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260',
            id: 6,
            quantity: 1
        },
        ]
    },
});
```

ProductCard.vue

```
<template>
  <ul
    class="
      px-32
      py-16
      grid
      row-auto
      gap-10
      grid-cols-1
      md:grid-cols-2
      xl:grid-cols-3
      2xl:grid-cols-4
    "
  >
    <li
      class="bg-white rounded-lg"
      v-for="cupcakes in cupcake"
      :key="cupcakes.id"
    >
      <img
        class="rounded-md w-screen object-cover max-h-60"
        :src="cupcakes.image"
      />
      <div class="py-2 px-8 text-gray-600">
        <span class="px-10 text-xl font-bold"> {{ cupcakes.title }}</span>
        <span class="px-10 text-xl font-bold">${{ cupcakes.price }}</span>
        <button
          class="
            bg-purple-200
            font-bold
            px-3
            mt-2
            text-xl
            py-4
            mb-4
            w-full
            rounded-md
            transition-all
            hover:bg-purple-300
          "
          type="button"
          v-on:click="addToCart(cupcakes)"
        >
          Add to Cart
        </button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    cupcake() {
      return this.$store.state.cupcake;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    addToCart(cupcakes) {
      this.$store.state.cart.push({
        title: cupcakes.title,
        price: cupcakes.price,
        image: cupcakes.image,
        id: cupcakes.id,
        quantity: cupcakes.quantity,
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Minicart.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="bg-white border-2 border-gray-500 rounded-md absolute right-16">
    <div
      class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-20 m-5"
      v-for="carts in cart"
      :key="carts.id"
    >
      <img class="w-24" :src="carts.image" alt="" />
      <div class="grid grid-rows-3">
        <strong class="tracking-wider font-bold">{{ carts.title }}</strong>
        <p class="tracking-wider font-bold">
          {{ carts.quantity }} x ${{ carts.price }}
        </p>
        <button
          class="bg-gray-500 rounded p-2 tracking-wider font-bold text-white"
          v-on:click="removeItem(carts)"
        >
          remove
        </button>
        <button type="button" v-on:click="increase(carts)">Increase</button>
        <button type="button" v-on:click="deccrease(carts)">Deccrease</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex mx-5 my-8 justify-between">
      <span
        class="tracking-wider text-xl p-4 font-bold justify-center align-middle"
        >Total: ${{ total }}</span
      >
      <button
        v-on:click="clearCart"
        type="button"
        href=""
        class="
          bg-red-400
          p-4
          rounded
          tracking-wider
          text-white text-xl
          font-bold
        "
      >
        Clear Cart
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    cart() {
      return this.$store.state.cart;
    },
    total: function () {
      let total = 0;
      for (let carts of this.$store.state.cart) {
        total += carts.price * carts.quantity;
      }
      return total.toFixed(2);
    },
  },
  methods: {
    removeItem: function (carts) {
      this.$store.state.cart.splice(carts, 1);
    },
    increase: function (carts) {
      carts.quantity += 1;
    },
    deccrease: function (carts) {
      if (carts.quantity > 1) {
        carts.quantity -= 1;
      } else {
        this.$store.state.cart.splice(carts, 1);
      }
    },
    clearCart: function () {
      let length = this.$store.state.cart.length;
      this.$store.state.cart.splice(0, length);
      console.log(length);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like that. Demo https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-shirley-dgg10

Template:

```
<button
      class="bg-purple-200 font-bold px-3 mt-2 text-xl py-4 mb-4 w-full 
      rounded-md transition-all hover:bg-purple-300"
      type="button"
      v-on:click="addToCart(cupcakes)"
      :disabled="checkCart(cupcakes.id)"
    >
    Add to Cart
</button>
```

Methods:

```
checkCart(id) {
      return this.$store.state.cart.find((item) => item.id === id);
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add this disabled-method to your button, it will be disabled, if the cupcake is already in the cart, and you can still add the other cupcakes:

```
<button
      class="
        ...
      "
      type="button"
      v-on:click="addToCart(cupcakes)"
      :disabled="{ cart.includes(cupcakes) }"
    >
      Add to Cart
    </button>
```

Your AddToCart-function could also be rewritten to:

```
addToCart(cupcakes) {
  this.$store.state.cart.push(cupcakes);
},
```

Comment: to use the full functionality of vuex I strongly suggest making use of mutations and actions when changing data in the store. [Documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html)

Comment: Thank you and thank you for a shorter version of my function, much appreciated!